# Why are my Three.js objects displaying at the same time and not individually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I have two 3d models I'm trying to switch between. Currently I can click a button after the first page load to display either of the two 3d objects, but when I try to switch between them they always load both objects at the same time.

How do I fix this?

```
$(".choice:not(a)").click(function(){


    // get the id of chosen item


    let id = $(".chosen").attr("id");
    id = id.match(/\d+$/)[0];

    let item;

        // change variables for id

        if(id == 1){

            item = 'first.mtl';
            objects = 'first.obj';

        }else if(id == 2){

            item = 'second.mtl';
            objects = 'second.obj';

        }

        // Problem is here they keep loading at the same time.


            new THREE.MTLLoader()
            .setPath( 'models/obj/' )
            .load( gun, function ( materials ) {
                materials.preload();
                new THREE.OBJLoader()
                    .setMaterials( materials )
                    .setPath( 'models/obj/' )
                    .load( objects, function ( object ) {
                        object.position.y = 0;
                        scene.add( object );

                            object.visible = botonsON;


                    }, onProgress, onError );

            } );


   });
```

Comment: if you want i can fix that for you but you have to provide a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working as intended. All visibility properties of your objects share the same boolean botonsON. If its true you are just displaying all of them. You are also loading models every time the user switches which is pointless. I suggest you load the objects once, add them to the scene and save to some variables. Make one of them not visible at the start. Whenever user clicks simply do

```
object1.visible != object1.visible
object2.visible != object2.visible
```